# sparkfun CAN Bus shield for arduino

Tags: arduino, can-bus

I am trying to use the sparkfun CAN Bus shield https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10039

I can send data using this library 
https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield

but I can not read data, has anyone had the same problem and solved it?

Comment: Hi Fredrick, please share the code you are using to setup the CAN and read data. Also, are you sure that you successfully send the data? Please share the relevant code as well.